# Web2Py: Not track changes between modules

Tags: python, module, web2py

I have two modules that work together.

For example, I have *user.py* and *email.py*. *user.py* have a function to verify a register and *email.py* have a function to send a email of confirmation. I import in controller *user.py*, and *user.py* import *email.py*.

with:

```
from gluon.custom_import import track_changes
track_changes(True)
```

I detect changes in *user.py*, but not in *email.py*. I tried to put `track_changes` also in *user.py* and it doesn't work.

Are there something that I can do without restart server/web2py?

Web2Py: 2.16.1-stable+timestamp.2017.11.14.05.54.25 (I try with *.exe and *.py)

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Thanks!

Comment: What do your import statements look like?

Comment: In controller `from user import User`, and in _user.py_ `from email import Email`. User and Email are classes. I try also like `import email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web2py uses a custom importer that first attempts to import a module via the standard Python built-in method and then looks in the application's /modules folder only if the built-in method fails. Only modules found via this custom import process are trackable.

Because user.py has already been imported and email.py is in the same folder as user.py, the Python built-in import method knows to look in the same folder for the `email` module when it encounters `import email` within the user.py file. As a result, the web2py custom import process does not kick in, and the module is therefore not tracked.

I suppose this behavior could be changed, but for now, that's how it works, so your second import will not be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with Modules not being reimported after I had made changes. `track_changes` never worked for me. In the end i added this to my db.py file.

```
import importlib
import sys
# Now import all your modules
import Common
importlib.reload(sys.modules['Common'])
```

This has worked well for me. I understand it should be removed when it goes to production.